# Caclulating cross-sales pair values from transactions (SQL/PySpark)

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have the following 2 tables and desired output as the following:

1) Table with periods where I have pair of items (all combination of items during the period) (table_1)

```
period_id start_date end_date item_1 item_2
   1         01-01     01-07    A      B
   1         01-01     01-07    A      C
   1         01-01     01-07    B      C
   2         02-01     02-07    D      E
   2         02-01     02-07    D      F
   2         02-01     02-07    E      F
   .           .         .      .      .
   .           .         .      .      .
   .           .         .      .      .
   n         mm-dd     mm-dd    X      Y
```

2) Table with a transaction date, item transaction,and a basket id (table_2)

```
basket_id date_id item_id
   1       01-03    A
   1       01-03    B
   2       01-04    C
   2       01-04    G
   2       01-04    P
   2       01-04    A
   3       02-02    D
   3       02-02    E
   3       02-02    I
   4       02-05    D
   4       02-05    E
   4       02-05    F
   4       02-05    M
   .         .      .
   .         .      .
   .         .      . 
   n       mm-dd    X
```

I would like to count per period the baskets when the pair of items were in the same basket
From the data dummy above what the outcome should be:

```
period_id start_date end_date item_1 item_2 common_baskets
   1         01-01     01-07    A      B          1
   1         01-01     01-07    A      C          2
   1         01-01     01-07    B      C          0
   2         02-01     02-07    D      E          2
   2         02-01     02-07    D      F          1
   2         02-01     02-07    E      F          1
   .           .         .      .      .          .
   .           .         .      .      .          .
   .           .         .      .      .          .
   n         mm-dd     mm-dd    X      Y          N
```

table_1 contains ~1 million rows, table_2 ~1 billion stored on Hadoop,  so it  is impossible to loop over stuff.

I can query using PySpark, but at first it would be nice to find a logic that can resolve this thing without loops, I don't necessarily need a piece of code, rather thought process, hence I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like `join`s and `group by`:

```
select p.period_id, start_date, end_date, item_1, item_2,
       count(b2.basket_id)
from periods p left join
     basket b
     on p.item_1 = b.item_id and
        b.date_id >= p.start_date and
        b.date_id <= p.end_date left join
     basket b2
     on p.item_1 = b2.item_id and
        b2.basket_id = p.basket_id 
group by p.period_id, start_date, end_date, item_1, item_2;
```